# Подгрузка файла по URL curl

Tags: php

Я подгружаю файл, который лежит в директории моего сайта для передачи на сервер и отправляю по Curl

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['file' => new CURLFile(__DIR__ . "/IMG_3382.jpg", 'image/gif')]);
```

А как брать файл не из своей директории, а по ссылке с другого сайта?

Comment: Скачивать на свой, отсылать и удалять скачанный

Comment: @wnull а как это реализовать ?

Comment: читайте про функции `file_put_contents()` или `copy()`.